# pyenchant broker with only Hspell provider [<Enchant: Hspell Provider>], no Aspell provider

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, aspell, pyenchant

I installed pyenchant (Ubuntu 17.0, Spyder 3.2.4, Python 3.6.1 64bits) using

```
pip install pyenchant
```

When I am executing

```
import enchant
b = enchant.Broker()
print(b.describe())
```

I am getting

```
[<Enchant: Hspell Provider>]
```

I was able to find out that that the output should contain at least

```
[<Enchant: Ispell Provider>, <Enchant: Myspell Provider>, <Enchant: Aspell Provider>]
```

For whatever reason my pyenchant creates the broker with only a Hebrew (hspell) provider on the list. I would like to be using "us_EN" dictionary, but the list of available dictionaries is either [] if I do not have hspell installed, or ['he'] after I do install hspell.
I do have aspell installed in my system, I triple-checked.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.